Issue when sharing file and text - Only shows text in email
when i am sharing file with WebShare Api its not showing the text while sharing the file its showing text only in email
const file = new File([this.pdfBlobforData], `${name}.pdf`, {
      type: 'application/pdf',
    });
    if (navigator.canShare && navigator.canShare({ files: [file] })) {
      navigator.share({
        title: 'Check out this',
        text: 'Check it out!',
        files: [file], // Share the PDF file
      }).then(() => {
        console.log('Shared successfully');
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error sharing', error);
      });
    } else {
      alert('Your browser does not support sharing files.');
    }

i want to share file along with title and text

Could be a bug in outlook, checking in windows system (Chrome) it does not work great when I checked in local

and also the issue is in some of the apps it's not showing the text and tittle it just shows pdf
